# grunt doesn't see import in sass file

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

grunt work very well.

I use this properties in Gruntfile.js for css

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'src/css/style.css': 'src/css/style.scss'
            }
        }
    },      


    cssmin: {
        combine: {
            files: {
                'css/cssmin.css': ['src/css/style.css']
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: 'src/js/*.js',
            tasks: ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify']
        },

        css: {
            files: 'src/css/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass', 'cssmin']
        }
    }
```

So everthing work cool, but in css folder I have three files:
1. style.css
2. style.scss
3. snippets.scss

So, for test I set in there simple properties. In style.scss

```
$color: #fff;

@import 'snippets.scss';

body{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #000;
    color: $color;
    font-size: 14px;
}

p{
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

And so in snippets.scss:

```
body{
    width: 10000px;
    height: 50000px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

So when I turn grunt on, all work good and in file cssmin.css I get inline properties:

```
body{height:100px;width:100px;background:#000;color:#fff;font-size:14px}p{color:#000;font-size:20px;background:#90ee90}
```

But you see, there are not any properties from import, from @import 'snippets.scss'.
What's wrong I do? As you can see I don't use compass plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What can you see in console during compiling your output CSS? Can you post it here?

Another thing is, that if you don't need to generate both CSS files: `styles.css` and `snippets.css`, it will be better to rename your `snippets.scss` to `_snippets.scss` and change you styles to:

```
$color: #fff;

@import '_snippets';

body{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #000;
    color: $color;
    font-size: 14px;
}

p{
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

You will have only one output CSS file and result will be more cleaner.

Comment: Done, without errors.
Completed in 1.248s at Wed Jul 09 2014 12:57:30 GMT+0400 (Арабское время (зима))
 - Waiting...

Comment: You see I tried to do what you adviced me, but it doesn't work anyway. Maybe I have done bad properties in Gruntfile.js? Should I say to grunt that it watch for all .scss files in folder? Or in any case if there is in style.scss property @import - it must work?

Comment: If Grunt complie your basic styles.scss, it must compile also all impoted _filename.sccs files inside. It's weird. What kind of SASS do you use? And if you write some nonsense (some bug) into styles.scss or _snippets.scss, what does it happen after restarting grunt server? Can you see any error message after restart?

Comment: When I write frunt in command line I get this C:\Users\designer\Desktop\grunt2>grunt

Running "jshint:<%= pkg.name %>" (jshint) task
>> 3 files lint free.

Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
File src/js/concated.js created.

Running "uglify:my_target" (uglify) task
File js/js.min.js created: 121 B → 90 B

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
File src/css/style.css created.

Running "cssmin:combine" (cssmin) task
File css/cssmin.css created: 298 B → 159 B

Running "watch" task
Waiting...

Comment: When I change files in style.scss I get this

>> File "src\css\style.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
File src/css/style.css created.

Running "cssmin:combine" (cssmin) task
File css/cssmin.css created: 321 B → 177 B

Done, without errors.
Completed in 1.205s at Fri Jul 11 2014 14:50:38 GMT+0400 (Арабское время (зима))
 - Waiting...

 That's all.